# UITableviewCell in storyboard is not initialized

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create UITableView with storyboard as the pic shows:

[image]

and the delegate methods in ITViewController.m is as below:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ITTableViewCell *cell = (ITTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ITTableViewCell"];

    return cell;
}
```

When I ran my app, I got the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

It seems that no cell has been initialized, how can I fix this problem? thks!

Comment: your cell's identifier must be "ITTableViewCell" in your story board.

Comment: Storyboards make it very simple - all you need to check is that the reuse identifier specified in the storyboard for your `ITTableViewCell` is `@"ITTableViewCell"`.

Comment: @rajesh I have solved by setting the identifier. I did not see the identifier property because of somehow hidding the property list of tableviewcell. Thks!

Answer (score -1):

you can initialize cell like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ITTableViewCell";       

     UTTableViewCell *cell = (UTTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
     }  

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to have an if(cell==nil) clause if the cell is made in the storyboard -- it will never be nil (assuming you use the correct identifier).

Comment: yeah thats the old way of doing it, you no longer have to do that